# Why does the three methods of reversing used not give the expected output?

Tags: python

As the title says, I have the following array,

```
arr = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974]
```

I then reverse it using either of the following methods

```
In [01]: arr[::-1]
Out[01]: [8974, 221, 2, 69, 7]
```

Using `.reverse()`

```
In [01]: arr.reverse()

In [02]: print(arr)
Out[02]: [8974, 221, 2, 69, 7]
```

Using `reversed(arr)`

```
In [01]: list(reversed(arr))
Out[01]: [8974, 221, 2, 69, 7]
```

Clearly in all instances the output should be `[8974, 221, 69, 7, 2]`

I am using Python 3.9.5. Does anyone know why this behaviour is observed?

Comment: Why do you expect the output you get to be different? You are reversing the list not sorting in reverse order. `sorted(arr, reverse=True)` would sort in reverse order

Answer (score 5):

I think you want your output to be sorted. You can try code in this way:

```
arr = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974]
sorted(arr,reversed=True)
```

Using .reverse()

```
In [01]: arr.sort().reverse()

In [02]: print(arr)
Out[02]: [8974, 221, 2, 69, 7]
```

Using reversed(arr)

```
In [01]: list(reversed(sorted(arr)))
Out[01]: [8974, 221, 2, 69, 7]
```

Comment: 1 and 3) Should be `sorted(arr, reverse=True)`

Comment: I left the 3 as it is because OP  wanted to use `reversed` function

Comment: The in-place `list.sort` method accepts an argument `reverse` that can be used to sort in reverse order: `arr.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: It can be done using a single statement too. I have written in  three ways because I assumed OP wanted to use those 3 functions